# comparing two ms access backend databases of an asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, gridview, datatable

at our office we take daily backup of ASP.net application ms access backend

for the next few days we need to evaluate the changes made to records in the database tables

at the end of each day i want to compare 2 access databases first database is the backup of **yesterday** and second database is the backup of **today**

i thought of the following algorithm, please read carefully and tell me how to proceed to compare the datatables / gridviews

i need to display th rows / cells containing the differences / updates / deleted data

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Partial Class MoKoTrack
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim myDB = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|database.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")

    Session("CurrentDB") = myDB


    myDB.open()
    Dim mytables = myDB.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {})

    Dim CurrentTable As String
    Dim ee As Integer = mytables.Rows.Count
    Dim OriginalTables(ee) As String
    Dim BackupTables(ee) As String
    Dim X As Integer = 0
    For i = 1 To mytables.Rows.Count
        CurrentTable = mytables.Rows(i - 1).Item(2).ToString
        If mytables.Rows(i - 1).Item(3).ToString = "TABLE" Or mytables.Rows(i - 1).Item(3).ToString = "VIEW" Then
            If CurrentTable.Contains("Backup") Then
                BackupTables(X) = CurrentTable
            Else
                OriginalTables(X) = CurrentTable
            End If
            X = X + 1
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 0 To BackupTables.Count - 1
        If Not BackupTables(i) = "" Then
            CompareTable(BackupTables(i))

        End If
    Next
    myDB.Close()
End Sub

Sub CompareTable(ByVal BackupTableName As String)
    Dim OriginalTable As New DataTable
    Dim BackupTable As New DataTable
    Dim ModificationsTable As New DataTable

    Dim myDB = Session("CurrentDB")
    Dim FinalSQLString = "SELECT * FROM [" + BackupTableName + "]"
    Dim myDBCommand = New OleDbCommand(FinalSQLString, myDB)
    'Generate a temporary reader to get the number of cases
    Dim myReader As IDataReader = myDBCommand.ExecuteReader()

    'Dim myColumns = myReader.GetSchemaTable
    'For I = 1 To myColumns.Rows.Count
    '    OriginalTable.Columns.Add(myColumns.Rows(I - 1).Item(0).ToString())
    'Next I
    BackupTable.Load(myReader)

    Dim OriginalTableName = Left(BackupTableName, Len(BackupTableName) - 6)
    Dim FinalSQLString2 = "SELECT * FROM [" + BackupTableName + "]"
    Dim myDBCommand2 = New OleDbCommand(FinalSQLString, myDB)
    'Generate a temporary reader to get the number of cases
    Dim myReader2 As IDataReader = myDBCommand.ExecuteReader()
    OriginalTable.Load(myReader2)

    'Dim myGrid As New GridView
    'myGrid.DataSource = OriginalTable
    'myGrid.DataBind()
    'Me.form1.Controls.Add(myGrid)

    'Dim myGrid2 As New GridView
    'myGrid2.DataSource = BackupTable
    'myGrid2.DataBind()
    'Me.form1.Controls.Add(myGrid2)


    For i = 0 To OriginalTable.Rows.Count - 1
        For t = 0 To OriginalTable.Columns.Count - 1

        Next
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

i am using the following VBA code to rename backup database tables into "tablebackup"

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim tdf As TableDef

For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
  tdf.Name = tdf.Name & "backup"
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a ModifiedOn field for each table and extract the rows that have been modified since the last day. You can compare the modified ones (the ones that exist in the backup) and write out all new ones (the ones that don't).